# How can i vertical align center forms

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

Before i ask i must first say i tried vertical methods align, it didnt work so i must post this problem of mine.Sry it might be trivial question,but im struggling with it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <section>
        <h1>Signup</h1>
            <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some description of the other methods you have tried. That will help others narrow down their suggestions. I would also suggest filling out the title of your post so that it reads like a full question: "How can I _____ ?" That will help people understand what you would like the outcome of the code you're sharing to be.

Comment: Oke thx on tip,im new around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `form-control` class with each input element.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password">
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy, on quick and precise answer :)